# PHP-ORACLE loop in a update statement

Tags: php, oracle

I have to create a page that does a simple update on a simple field with a string user gives.
For this I have created a form that stores the user string in the variable called $matricula.
Then I tried to update but the page never ends loading.

The form:

```
        <form id="formulario" action='<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>' method="post">
        <h4>Cambio de Matricula</h4>
                <label for="consig">Consignment</label><br>
                <input type="text" name="consignment" id="consignment" required />
                <label for="matricula">Matricula Nueva </label>
                <input type="text" name="matricula" id="matricula"/>
                <input type="submit" name="Cambiar"  value="Cambiar"/>
        </form>

$matricula = trim($_POST['matricula']);
$consignment = trim($_POST['consignment']);
```

The update:

```
    if (isset($_POST['Cambiar'])) {
        $update  = "UPDATE PICKING_ALBARANESAIMPRIMIR SET ZEL_EAN='".$matricula."' where PEDIDOONLINE ='".trim($consignment)."'";
        $stidd =oci_parse($conexion, $update);
        oci_execute($stidd, OCI_DEFAULT);
        echo "actualizado";
        
        }
```

In case you wonder, yes, when I do the update in oracle it does work + I'm using same $matricula value and $consignment value, also, $conexion cant be wrong, I took that from another php that works on the same path.

[Oracle screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNnQo.png)

This is not the full php, if you need any info beside that I will be checking to edit :) (full php is not that large but I feel like I shouldn't post 100 lines of code).

Comment: **NEVER** use string concatenation to build queries as it leaves your application vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. If someone enters `'||(SELECT password_hash FROM secret_table WHERE username='Admin')||'` into the `matricula` input then your query will update value to the hash of the administrator's password and you have a big security issue. Use bind variables instead.

Comment: @MT0 This is part of a intern consult on a DMZ, its pretty safe :)

Comment: One of the biggest security threats is the insider threat (see Edward Snowden as an example). Just because you deem it to be "safe" does not mean you should not follow best practice and using bind variables is simple enough that you should **NEVER** need to use string concatenation to pass user input into a query.

Comment: I know but at this point im only trying to make it work, not to add more things I dont understand to it :) @MT0

Comment: "... but the page never ends loading" - when you tested it, you ran the UPDATE statement "in Oracle" (I presume you meant in a tool you use to access the database; which one was it? SQL Developer? SQL*Plus? dBeaver? Something else?). If you just tested it and left it be, then this piece of PHP code is trying to do the update, but has to **wait** until another session - which affected rows to be updated - either **commits** or **rollbacks** that transaction. Therefore, try to do so in that tool of yours (commit or rollback) and then run PHP script again. What happens?

Comment: @Littlefoot The tool is SQL Developer, I did what you said, now the page is not stuck loading!!! Thanks, sadly the update is not doing the update xd, it just does not pop any error. But I guess thats another story. I also did a echo $update and I see it allright, so it must be something that is done afterwards.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I just found the reason, besides Littlefoot comment :

Having to either commit or rollback the update I did in the SQL tool.

Also had to change this line because it was not commiting the update:

```
 oci_execute($stidd, OCI_DEFAULT);
```

This line with OCI_DEFAULT does not commit the update.

This one does:

```
 oci_execute($stidd);
```